# How to detect silence in an audio stream with pydub?

Tags: python, pydub

I want to monitor an audio streaming for silences. Any idea how I can do this ? it's a stream, not an audio file.

Comment: Hope the answer below helps, if you can describe the stream data in more detail I can make the answer more specific

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best bet is to grab chunks from the stream (I'd advise 50 millisecond chunks since one complete wave form at 20Hz is 50ms), and construct an AudioSegment using this data.

Once you've done that you'll be able to use the `AudioSegment().dBFS` property to get a rough measure of the average loudness of that chunk. Once you get a sense for where the highs and lows are you can set a threshold below which will be considered silence.

You can of course determine the silence threshold automatically as well, but that'll probably require keeping track of loudest and quietest signal level in the last X seconds, and probably using some kind of decay as well.

**Note:** The method I've described above is definitely not the fastest way to do this, but pydub does not natively handle streaming. That said, it's probably the *simplest* way to accomplish your goal with pydub.

Comment: Thanks @Jiaaro. I was a little hasty and decided to install a [silence detector](http://www.pira.cz/show.asp?art=silence) at the streaming source itself. It's for radio broadcasting. Sometimes we don't receive any signal in the soundcard and we want to monitor this. The software analyzes the signal that is received in the soundcard and if there's nothing for more than X seconds it can perform a variety of tasks (configurable). I configured it to send an HTTP request to my monitoring web app. So the problem is solved for me but from the other endpoint :)

Comment: any other solution?

Comment: @Jiarro is there a way to stream with pydub that you know of?

Comment: @Kazanz There is not, sorry